# What is the simplest way to understand Turing machines and the busy beaver problem?

Tags: turing-machines, busy-beaver

The Wikipedia description has way too much math.

Comment: The "[Informal description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Informal_description)" section of the Wikipedia page on Turing machines contains very little maths. Since Turing machines are an object of mathematics, I dispute the assertion that it's possible for the rest of that page to contain "way too much math". It's like complaining that the page about Shakespeare contains "way too much English".

Comment: You are asking for something that constitutes a whole book chapter -- that's too broad for SE. I recommend you access a variety of sources first (and check your mathematical prerequisites) and share *your* understanding; fixing misunderstandings is much more feasible in scope.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the OP is right when stating that Wikipedia should have much more informal presentations for people who will not read anything formalized. But he should take this up with wikipedia, not with SE, unless he is looking for comments on his presentation, in which case he should be explicit about it.  He actually provided the answer too.

Comment: Since you actually provided both the question and the answer, I can
only presume you are looking for feedback, not for an answer. You
should be explicit about it, or about any other goal you may have.
I see that as useful, but my opinion is not necessarily shared. And
Wikipedia would be a better place, though it is not always very
open. cc @Raphael

Comment: @babou Where, of course, taking something up with Wikipedia means just edting the page. Meanwhile, [Stack Exchange explicitly encourages people to answer their own questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so there is no need for chilicuil to justify or explain doing so.

Comment: @babou I am hesitant to support the demand for "plain English" explanations for everything. But that aside, the question as phrased is just, "Please re-explain until I understand". The subject is broad, it's unclear what would help the OP, and "simplest" is subjective. In other words, this is not a good question for SE. The fact that the OP provides an "answer" does not help; any "question" should enable others to answer, too.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their wiliness to help, I didn't though it could bother someone or that the question/answer combo couldn't be well received on SE, the original question/answer is on quora, http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-way-to-understand-Turing-machines-and-the-busy-beaver-problem and to my understanding is the best explanation I found on internet about the bb problem. Quora requires registration to see the full answer therefore I registered and copied the content here, if it's not right I'll copy it to my blog.

Comment: As I said, I find it important to have presentation for the
layman. This one is nice for BB, but could possibly be improved: it is
really hard work to do it. However you should be more careful when
copying content. For one thing, Quora requires you to reference them
when copying content. So does SE. It is in the terms of use (a
contractual, not a copyright matter). You might be excused by
permission from the author. Then, it is considered proper to always
attribute texts to their authors, even when under most free or
Creative Common licenses, and it is legally required in many countries. @Raph

Answer (score 3):

From [quora.com](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-way-to-understand-Turing-machines-and-the-busy-beaver-problem):

> A Turing machine is a computer (PC, Mac, iPhone or Conway's Game of Life - pick whichever is most familiar) with unlimited storage (memory, hard disk, doesn't matter). Assume you can program the computer in some programming language, and that you're interested in what it can and cannot compute. "Compute" means "read some input, do stuff, write some output".
>
> This is not the usual description of a Turing machine, of course, but for the study of computability - which is mostly what Turing machines are good for - it's completely equivalent.
>
> The Busy Beaver problem is this: suppose I challenge you to write a computer program (again, pick your favorite programming language) whose sole purpose in life is to print a long string of dots and then stop. If the length of your program is limited to k characters, how long of a string can you make?
>
> It should be clear that this question has an answer, for any choice of programming language and any given limit k. After all, there are only finitely many possible computer programs of length, say, 10,000 characters in, say, C++; some of them print finite strings of dots, and of all the ones that do, we can pick the one (or ones) that print the absolutely longest string.
>
> If you happen to know something about programming, it should also be clear that as soon as k becomes reasonably large to accommodate some non-trivial programs, the answer will be incredibly humungous. It's quite easy, for example, to write a computer program that prints 100^{100} dots and then stops, and in most reasonable programming languages this shouldn't take up more than a few hundred characters to implement. With some cleverness you can get much higher numbers.
>
> The Busy Beaver function is a table that lists, for any given k, the answer to this problem - the length of the longest string of dots you can achieve with a program of length k that prints such a string and stops. This function, or table, is pretty wild: it can be shown that it grows faster than any computable function. Therefore it is itself non-computable. It's unknowable in a pretty strong sense.
>
> If you don't know what "programming language" means or what programming languages can do, you can just imagine that you're giving a friend a notebook with very precise instructions such that, if your friend follows those instructions, she will end up writing a great number of dots on a very large piece of paper. You needn't assume the friend is a math genius, but you may assume she's immortal, very patient and capable of following simple instructions like "write the number 6 on the yellow sticky note" or "read the number on the orange sticky note, erase it and replace it with the next counting number". It's fine if she can't count beyond a billion herself: with enough sticky notes we can help her overcome that.

Comment: Why don't you try to include a short version of this in the "busy beaver" article of wikipedia, presenting it as a very informal introduction for non technical people, explainig why it is important.